# Wrong deps version installed by NPM 2

Tags: node.js, npm

react-bootstrap@0.26.4 depends on react@^0.13.3 but react@0.14.3 gets installed as a dependency. It also installs react@0.13.3 in the top level of node_modules (which is weird but fine). The 0.14.3 version breaks my application.

I expect only react@0.13.3 to be installed and not in the top level but in node_modules/react-bootstrap/node_modules/react

Why do I get react@0.14.3?

I have also tried adding react@0.13.3 in peerDependencies but I still get 0.14.3. I have also tried using npm 3, but doing a clean `npm install` for the app I'm building with npm 3 takes 75 minutes, so I'm hoping that there is a way to install react-bootstrap with npm 2.

```
kullervo: ~/tmp
$ mkdir test-react-bootstrap

kullervo: ~/tmp
$ cd test-react-bootstrap

kullervo: ~/tmp/test-react-bootstrap
$ npm install react-bootstrap@0.26.4
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency react@^0.13 included from react-bootstrap will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency react@>=0.11.0 included from uncontrollable will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency react@>=0.13.0 included from react-overlays will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
react@0.13.3 node_modules/react
└── envify@3.4.0 (through@2.3.8, jstransform@10.1.0)

react-bootstrap@0.26.4 node_modules/react-bootstrap
├── classnames@2.2.1
├── keycode@2.1.0
├── dom-helpers@2.4.0
├── lodash-compat@3.10.1
├── react-prop-types@0.3.0 (warning@2.1.0)
├── babel-runtime@5.8.34 (core-js@1.2.6)
├── react@0.14.3 (envify@3.4.0, fbjs@0.3.2)
├── react-overlays@0.4.4 (react-prop-types@0.2.2, warning@2.1.0)
└── uncontrollable@3.2.0 (invariant@2.2.0)

kullervo: ~/tmp/test-react-bootstrap
$ grep version node_modules/react-bootstrap/package.json | head -n 1
  "version": "0.26.4",

kullervo: ~/tmp/test-react-bootstrap
$ grep version node_modules/react-bootstrap/node_modules/react/package.json | head -n 1
  "version": "0.14.3",

kullervo: ~/tmp/test-react-bootstrap
$ grep version node_modules/react/package.json | head -n 1
  "version": "0.13.3",

kullervo: ~/tmp/test-react-bootstrap
$ node -v
v0.12.9

kullervo: ~/tmp/test-react-bootstrap
$ npm -v
2.14.9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like npm 2 is just plain broken. By upgrading all my app's deps, I was able to use latest version of node and npm, and suddenly the performance is good. Case closed. Lesson learned: Don't use npm 2.